# Error while connecting to DocumentDB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect DocumentDB and saving the records into it. However, I am getting following error while saving the records.

> "ExceptionMessage": "Service is currently unavailable.\r\nActivityId: 210604a7-0efd-41e3-855c-df70b98c2f5f, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.19.1 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.15063.0",

Also it is not able to connect the documentDB though the connection string, key everything is correct.
When I tried through DocumentDB studio it is running well.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Could you specify or share the code snippet that is used to connect to the account? (without account keys real value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issug long time back, and try changing the connection in the Advanced Settings of the Target Information tab from DirectTCP to Gateway. This helps when there is a firewall.

Otherwise you need to send an email to  **`askdocdb@microsoft.com`**

Comment: But where should I do these changes ?